How to export collection of Hyper-V VMs for "backup" purposes
At Hyper-V, any time it is needed to export just one VM we can use the "Export VM" option. This time, I need to export a collection of the VMs that we are running through Hyper-V and the use of the "Export VM" option one by one seems to be a waist of time.
Is there a "non manual" way to do this every weekend? something like a cron job for Linux?

Why not actually backup these VMs with an actual backup solution?

Hyper-V VMs are usually stored in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Virtual Hard Disks, you could set up your VM for shutting down, then backing up the files and restarting again.
